# For loop VBA not populating cells correctly

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have some code that worked fine: it opens a file name from a list, finds if it contains a quote, and returns the status into the list, but I added a For loop and found it only works when set to about "1 to 10". Anything much bigger returns the wrong value in several instances. What step have I missed? (I had commented out extra parts which have been removed here.)

```
Sub BadCharactersFinder()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim foundDoubleQuote As Variant
    Dim ClientID As String
    Dim PDSfilename As String
    Dim fname As String

    ClientID = ActiveCell.Value
    PDSfilename = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
    fname = "N:\DOWNLOAD\XYZfoldername\" & ClientID & "\original\" & XYZfilename

For i = 1 To 10

    Set WBopener = Application.Workbooks.Open(fname)
    Set foundDoubleQuote = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("""", ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows)

            If (Not foundDoubleQuote Is Nothing) Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = "Contains quotes"
            Else
                ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = "."
            End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.Height <> 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you use `I` are you trying to check 10 times for quotes, if so you are reopening the workbook each time.

Comment: Why are you looping `i` if you are not using it in the loop? What is it you want to loop through?

Comment: I'm drawing a file path from a list of clients and file names in an excel file. The goal is to open the file in the file path listed, check it for quotes, close the file, and mark the original list telling me whether or not it contains quotes. The for loop was meant to do this process for several items on the list.

Comment: @Derek Right now your `For` loop is just doing the same thing 10 times in a row, nothing is changing on each iteration.

Comment: If I copied this correctly, 
1. It should get the file path from the active cell and its row.
2. Open the file at the path it got.
3. Look inside it for quotes and
A. Return to the original spreadsheet to say quotes were found
or
B. Place a period.
5. Move to the next row.
The issue is that it will cycle through that as expected, but only for about 10 times.